# FLAG_SECURE not working on libgdx's AndroidApplication

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an Android game created with help of libGDX. I want to disable the ability to take screenshots.

For regular android activities you can use `getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` method. It works fine.

But it doesn't work with activities extended from `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication`. I'm still able to take screenshots.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `initialize` in AndroidApplication sets up the window parameters for a full-screen game, so it's overwriting your window parameters. So instead, put this in `onCreate` **after** you call `initialize`. Note that you should use `addFlags` instead of `setFlags` so you don't mess up the other flags that Libgdx set.

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```